# Is it possible to have a div bottom center aligned with the width?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a div center aligned (ie) always i need to have the div in bottom center with fixed position in a specified width. I know to have it left or right? is there is any way?

Comment: Try taking a look at the answer to this very similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042209/how-to-center-my-a-div-in-a-table-using-css/1042216#1042216

Comment: Also, define "bottom" - bottom of the viewable pane? Immediately below all content? At the bottom of the viewable pane unless the content extends below that? The centering component of this question is easily answered, but the whole question probably can't be answered satisfactorily without some clarification.

Comment: How to fake fixed in ie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319057/how-to-center-a-div-element-in-ie6

Comment: When you have an answer that fits your needs and is correct, consider marking it as accepted by click on the big tick next to the post.

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this may help you

css:

```
 #parent{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;   //width should be 100%
 } 
 #child{
    width:100px; //min width should give to center the div.
    margin:0px auto; //here it will make center 
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>
      centered div
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.myDiv
{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ivan, it's probably worth explaining that the width element is required in order for the `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` bit to work. Also, I don't think you need `position:fixed`.

Comment: Yes, the width is needed, else the div will have 100% width, and margins left and right make no difference :) position:fixed, because Webdevelopertut wanted the div to be positioned in the bottom center. I am not sure bottom: 0px; will work without any positioning.

Comment: margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto wont work with position's like absolute and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didnt work for me but here is what did slight modification of Shiva's Answer. Have a parent-child div combo where one grabs the bottom of the page and the other grabs the center 
like so

```
.bottomOfThePage{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.centerOfThePage{
    text-align: center;
    //other text stuff like color
 }
```

html

```
<div class="bottomOfThePage">
    <div class="centerOfThePage">
        <p>footerStuffHere</p>
    </div>
</div>
```